# How can I find all .txt files in specific directory, remove them and pack folder into archiv using bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, rm

I have this code, which has to find all .txt files and remove them

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/user_name -name "*.txt" | xargs rm
```

Is it correct ? How can I archive folder after that ?

Comment: Don't use `xargs` unless you understand the consequences. `find` has a delete option: `find /home/user_name -name "*.txt" -delete`. Use it! The best way to find out how to archive the folder is to google "How to archive folder linux"

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/user_name -type f -name "*.txt" -exec rm {} \;
# for your specific use case, you could also do
# find /home/user_name -type f -name "*.txt" -delete
# as @hek2mgl pointed out.
# You can have a more restricted search by using -type f
# You can archive the folder using the zip command like below
zip -r user_name.zip /home/user_name
```

---

<sup>**Note:** Read the manpage of `zip` to see the usage of `-r` parameter</sup>